# SQL Error (1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '6893Order '

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1292

When this MySql query is executed:

```
update order_line_item oli
inner join orders o
set oli.active_orders = o.valid
where oli.order_id = o.id
```

I keep getting this error:

> SQL Error (1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '6893Order '

Any suggestions?

Additional Info:

1. Both "active_orders" and "valid" are INT
2. order_line_item can reference the same order.id for multiple lines
3. Table examples (currently)

   ```
   table : order_line_item
   id  order_id    active_orders
   1   1   
   2   2   
   3   3   
   4   4   
   5   4   


   table : orders
   +-------+-------------+    
   |   id  |   valid     |     
   +-------+-------------+
   |   1   |       1     |   
   |   2   |       1     |   
   |   3   |       0     |  
   |   4   |       1     |  
   |   5   |       1     |   
   +-------+-------------+
   ```
4. With the query i'm trying to copy orders.valid and paste into orders_line_item.active_orders:

   ```
   table : order_line_item
   +-------+------------+-----------------+    
   |   id  |   order_id |   active_orders |     
   +-------+------------+-----------------+
   |   1   |   1        |        1        |   
   |   2   |   2        |        1        |   
   |   3   |   3        |        0        |  
   |   4   |   4        |        1        |  
   |   5   |   4        |        1        |   
   +-------+------------+-----------------+

   table : orders
   +-------+-------------+    
   |   id  |   valid     |     
   +-------+-------------+
   |   1   |       1     |   
   |   2   |       1     |   
   |   3   |       0     |  
   |   4   |       1     |  
   |   5   |       1     |   
   +-------+-------------+
   ```

Comment: Which of the columns in the query is declared to be `DOUBLE`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/). Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Barmar, that's the part that doesn't make sense to me.  the value i'm trying to copy over to 'active_orders' is an integer value.  No additional values are being joined.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from that query? I don't see any way it can produce that error.

Comment: i'm a novice at this, so i just assumed i'm wrong.  haha!  I checked the data, don't see anything that would throw the query off.  is there something else it could be?

Comment: See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c55fc1f7ff10205ece6b2552a7901164) i am follow your table and do like your and nothing error show up.. Desc your table

Answer (score 0):

You are say :

> 1. Both "active_orders" and "valid" are INT
> 2. order_line_item can reference the same order.id for multiple lines

[db<>fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c55fc1f7ff10205ece6b2552a7901164)

See in my demo i am make all colum to `INT` and do your update statement

```
update order_line_item oli
inner join orders o
set oli.active_orders = o.valid
where oli.order_id = o.id
```

And no error show up. The error

> SQL Error (1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '6893Order '

Seems pretty clear there are `DOUBLE`. Do you really run this query and got this error? Or please show the desc your table.

Comment: Yes, this is the only error that I am seeing.  From what you all are saying it sounds like a problem with my data?  I checked for anomalies and didn't find anything.  I have no idea what else it could be.

Comment: It can be the data. So value `6893Order` who have this value? which column? `valid` column?